# Convert long int to ASCII using sprintf

Tags: c

I want to use sprintf for converting long integer in to ASCII value, for example if long int val = 40000, i used

```
sprintf(buff, "%ld", val);
printf(%s\n", buff);
```

It is printing only d, instead of 40000. 
  if i change to unsigned long,

```
sprintf(buff, "%lu", val);
printf(%s\n", buff);
```

It is printing only u. It is problem with compiler/ToolChain?

Comment: **Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.** My crystal ball tells me `buff` is declared a `char*` with no dedicated storage space, or insufficient storage space, and find it inconveniently suspicious its declaration was not included in your post. If `%ld` were indeed broken, `sprintf` shouldn't be needed to demonstrate it, a direct `printf` should suffice.  Finally, `printf(%s\n", buff);` works considerably better (compiles and everything!) with an opening dbl-quote for the format string.

Comment: CNR: [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/RgddQ9)

Comment: which compiler you're using. Seems like some old versions of MSVC because Windows uses their own non-standard version of stdlib which doesn't support `l` or `ll` and you must use `%I32d` for long and `%I64d` for long long instead

Answer (score 0):

You may refer [this](http://www.keil.com/forum/3909/conversion-of-integer-to-ascii-for-display/)

```
void UlToStr(char *s, unsigned long bin, unsigned char n)
{
    s += n;
    *s = '\0';

    while (n--)
    {
        *--s = (bin % 10) + '0';
        bin /= 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, if i know many character(i.e unsigned char n). How can i calculate n in run time?

Comment: create a loop which would start at s and check the value, increasing counter at every step . if value ever equals to '\0', return the counter.

Comment: this is unnecessary because C can already print out integer values. The problem is the stdlib and/or format string

Comment: @Reshmikhanna, calculating the number of characters would be quite simple. You know the max value a `long int` can hold and you add a new decimal place every time a number is greater than `10^i` (10 to the `i`th power). So you would just have to loop until `10^i` is greater than the value of the variable. Then you know you need `i+1` characters

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc ageed. It was a brute approach